# Dynamically changing operator in C

Tags: c

Currently having many codes that only differ in 1 operator (e.g. + ,- ,* ,/ ,& ,| ,== , etc... )
Is it possible to combine these into one common function in C with the operator as a parameter ? Thank you.

**Example1**

```
   for (int y = 0; y < v3->y; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < v3->x; x++)
                {
                    v3->num[y][x] = v1->num[y][x] + v2->num[y][x];
                }
            }
```

**Example2**

```
   for (int y = 0; y < v3->y; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < v3->x; x++)
                {
                    v3->num[y][x] = v1->num[y][x] * v2->num[y][x];
                }
            }
```

**Example3**

```
   for (int y = 0; y < v3->y; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < v3->x; x++)
                {
                    v3->num[y][x] = v1->num[y][x] | v2->num[y][x];
                }
            }
```

**Not sure if possible, but Expected something like this...**

```
   for (int y = 0; y < v3->y; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < v3->x; x++)
                {
                    v3->num[y][x] = v1->num[y][x] operator v2->num[y][x];
                }
            }
```

Comment: You could wrap each operation in a simple 2-argument function and call them either directly or using a function pointer. A function pointer there is likely to perform slower, though, especially when the compiler could otherwise inline and optimize things.

Comment: By the way, do you maybe have a typo – should that be `x < v3->x`? :-)

Comment: You can also use a Macro. Operators are perfectly valid as macro arguments.

Comment: Although you could do any kind function pointer or macro solutions, I don't think you should. Your loops are not really that long or complicated. You can easily harm readability or prevent optimizations by adding more layers there.

Comment: Please note that "Is it possible?" and "Is it a good idea?" are very different questions. Almost everything in C is possible if you throw enough ugly dangerous macros on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PMF mentions in the comments, you can use a macro – either to wrap just the `v3 = v1 OP v2` computation, or the entire loop, such as here ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/seWEqnzdM))

```
// NB: v1, v2, v3 need to be simple identifiers, this macro is not safe otherwise
#define VLOOP(v3, v1, v2, op) \
    for (int y = 0; y < v3->y; y++) \
    for (int x = 0; x < v3->x; x++) \
    v3->num[y][x] = v1->num[y][x] op v2->num[y][x]

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    int **num;
} V;

void compute_sum(V* v3, V* v1, V* v2) {
    VLOOP(v3, v1, v2, +);
}

void compute_product(V* v3, V* v1, V* v2) {
    VLOOP(v3, v1, v2, *);
}

void compute_division(V* v3, V* v1, V* v2) {
    VLOOP(v3, v1, v2, /);
}

// etc...
```

Comment: You don't really want the semicolon at the end of the macro definition.  The invocation provides that.  The trailing semicolon breaks code like `if (a > b) VLOOP(…); else VLOOP(…);`.

Comment: This smells a lot like using the pre-processor for code generation though. If that's the purpose then maybe run an external script before compilation instead. Since indeed these macros aren't safe.

Comment: @Lundin Sure, if you're willing to add another moving part to your toolchain. For many simple uses, where you know the boundaries of what you're doing, a macro for generating a bit of code is just fine.

Comment: But since you already threw type safety out the window, might as well make a single function-like macro `compute(op1, op2, op3, operator)` which expands to the loop but uses `op` for the calculation. Probably a fair bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```c
#define DO_OP(op) for (int y = 0; y < v3->y; y++) \
            {\
                for (int x = 0; x < v3->x; x++)\
                {\
                    v3->num[y][x] = v1->num[y][x] op v2->num[y][x];\
                }\
            }
```

This does not reduce the size of the generated code, but the source will be much smoother. Use as

```
DO_OP(*)
DO_OP(/)
// etc...
```